# Can I detect if a magento function is being run as an API call?

Tags: api, magento

I know I can detect if a function is being run by an admin using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn();
```

But I'm not sure if there is a similar call to determine if the environment is an API call versus a web visit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could check if the `Mage_Api_Model_Server` singleton has been initialized:

```
$apiRunning = Mage::getSingleton('api/server')->getAdapter() != null;
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are coming across this question who need something that works for v2 of the API, this appears to work for me:

```
Mage::getSingleton('api2/request')->getApiType() !== null
```